# Uniqueness of $ \Delta u= \int _\Omega u(y)dy $ , $ x \in \Omega $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, poissons-equation

How can i show uniqueness of

$$ \Delta u= \int _\Omega u(y)dy  \phantom{2} ,\phantom{2} x \in \Omega   $$  $$ u=0  \phantom{2}, \phantom{2}   x \in \partial\Omega $$

I suppose that there are two solutions $u_1$ and  $u_2$ such that $w=u_1 - u_2$. Applying Green first identity , i cannot get $w=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply the equation by $u$ and integrate over $\Omega$. Integrating by parts on the left hand side we have
$$
-\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 = \left(\int_\Omega u\right)^2.
$$
Note that the left hand side is non-positive and the right hand side is non-negative.  Thus it must be the case that $u \equiv 0$.

Comment: How does the right hand side become  $ \int_\Omega u \int_\Omega u = \left(\int_\Omega u\right)^2. $

Comment: Think of $\int_\Omega u(y) dy$ as a constant, so when we integrate (say, integrate in $z$) we have $\int_\Omega (\int_\Omega u(y) dy) u(z) dz = \int_\Omega u(y)dy \cdot \int_\Omega u(z)dz.$

Comment: You're right. I got the point. Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck!